# Gradle 7.4.2 failure - Zip file "... app-debug.apk' already contains entry 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF', cannot overwrite

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I recently upgraded to Android Studio Hedgehog and Gradle V7.4.2. I can successfully build and run my app on my devices through Android Studio but I can't build a release apk package or successfully use the 'Rebuild Project' menu option. I'm getting this gradle exception (below) during the build process and I can't figure out the issue. I've manually deleted the .apk and the build process creates a new one each time, but then it seems to want to update the .apk a second time and fails. It happens for both release and debug builds.

I've read through all the posts with similar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF issues but couldn't find a solution.

How do I solve this?

I'd really appreciate your help on this. Thanks!

---

> Task :app:packageDebug FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> Zip file 'C:\Users\ptras\Documents\Projects\RTC B_MAIN_New\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk' already contains entry 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF', cannot overwrite

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }
    compileSdk 34
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.pjt.realtimecharts_v1'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 97
        versionName "1.69"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        archivesBaseName = "$applicationId-v$versionCode($versionName)"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'ReleaseBuild', 'true'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'ReleaseBuild', 'false'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            pickFirsts += ['**']
        }
        resources {
            excludes += ['.readme']
            pickFirsts += ['**']
        }
    }

    namespace 'com.pjt.realtimecharts_v1'
    lint {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        disable 'ResourceType'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation project(':ColorPickerPreference')
    implementation project(':ColorPicker')
    implementation project(':SliderPreference')
    implementation project(':achartengine')
    implementation project(':library')

    implementation 'androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}



To generate a valid signed Release APK for Google Play Store with Gradle 7.4.2.
```

Comment: I did some additional experiments, I can make the debug build fail by adding a signingConfigs block for debug and including  v1SignedingEnabled true and V2SigningEnabled true.

Comment: I solved the problem. I added the proper namespace option to all my lib build.gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding the proper namespace option to every build.gradle file (to match the AndroidManifest.xml package name) in my project and upgrading to gradle 8.0.2 from 7.4.2. Once I had the namespace options squared away the upgrade to gradle 8.0.2 went ahead without any issues. "Rebuild Project" and "Generate Signed Bundle / APK" menu options are both working again. Thanks!